# MongoDB with flexible fields. How to find all records with specific field name?

Tags: mongodb

I've a scheme

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("50ec1d93ba02ece1979ee4a5"), 
   "url" : "google.com" 
   "results" : [ 
      { "1357651347" : { "data1" : "a", "data2" : "b", "data3" : "c" }},
      { "1357651706" : { "data1" : "d", "data2" : "e", "data3" : "f" }},
      { "1357651772" : { "data1" : "g", "data2" : "h", "data3" : "i" }} 
    ]
}
```

I'm interested in the results with id `1357651706`. How do I get them (in PHP)?

Comment: Use $exists ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/ ) : `db.col.find({"results.1357651706": {$exists:true}})` or check if it is `null` (or not)

Comment: Check. Please post you answer ans an answer and i'll reward you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if something exists or you can check if something is null (or not).

So for `$exists` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/ ):

```
db.col.find({"results.1357651706": {$exists:true}})
```

And for checking if something is not `null`:

```
db.col.find({ "results.1357651706": {$ne: null} })
```

Note: It is normally better to use the `null` query the other way around to check if something is `null` and then do the process of judgement in your app. This way you can use sparse index on your query too to make it leaner.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Sammaye's answer, but consider reworking your schema to get rid of the dynamic field names which make queries like this awkward.

Something like this instead:

```js
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("50ec1d93ba02ece1979ee4a5"), 
   "url" : "google.com" 
   "results" : [ 
      { id: 1357651347, "data1" : "a", "data2" : "b", "data3" : "c" },
      { id: 1357651706, "data1" : "d", "data2" : "e", "data3" : "f" },
      { id: 1357651772, "data1" : "g", "data2" : "h", "data3" : "i" } 
    ]
}
```

Then you can query for the doc containing the result you're looking for like this:

```js
db.col.find({'results.id': 1357651706})
```